# Click a button on a website using C#

Tags: html, web-services, button, windows-phone-8

I'm developing an windowsphone 8 application.

My goal is to click on a certain button on a website from my code behind (C#).

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Example:

I have a button named 'MyButton" on Mainpage. Then in the event handler:

```
private void BtnMyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        //click button 'Search' on Google

    }
```

Comment: Could you be a little more clear? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: You could try to use selenium/webdriver. Not sure about windows phone and C# support though.

Comment: What I mean is I want to click a button on a website from my code. Simply like clicking 'Search' on www.google.com

Comment: I have editted my question. Hope you guys can understand.

Comment: Where is this website? Is it within a browser located in your application?  At the moment it is simply not clear where this button is, and how your application is connected to the browser that is displaying it

Comment: The website is on the internet. In my application, I created a HtmlDocument to hold all the html of that site. That's all. Sorry for missing information.

Answer (score 2):

You could register a Javascript function to call the click event.

In codebehind:

```
protected void BtnMyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> document.getElementById('yourButtonID').onclick(); </script>";
     ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "searchClick", script);
}
```

Or if you're using jQuery:

```
protected void BtnMyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> $('yourButtonID').Click(); </script>";
     ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "searchClick", script);
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to use your code? I'm new to winodws phone and I couldn't find ClientScript class anywhere.